# GWT - PopupPanel, change layout when flipped

Tags: css, gwt, popup

I'm creating a context menu for certain elements using a `PopupPanel`; the menu itself is going to be fairly large and complex. What I'm looking to do is to have a list of buttons, plus an image and some text, related to the element clicked.

My problem is that I'd like the buttons to always display directly under the clicked element, because that's convenient for the user; the issue is that when `PopupPanel` is near the edges of the screen, it automatically changes position to be fully visible, not aligning its left side to the element as usual. I *like* this behavior, but it moves the position of the buttons away.

So what I'd like to happen is: normally the buttons are on the left of the panel, the other stuff is to the right. When the panel is close to the right of the screen, I'd like the buttons to instead be on the right (and thus under the clicked element) and the other stuff on the left.

Is there a clever way to do this, either in GWT or better yet, using only CSS? `PopupPanel` itself doesn't seem to tell you when it's going to get flipped, sadly. The only solution I currently have is to manually check the position and width of the popup before showing it and adjust accordingly, but I'm hoping there's a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried the position callback? method: setPopupPositionAndShow(PopupPanel.PositionCallback callback);

Comment: I'm aware of this method, but what are you suggesting I do with it? All that lets me do is set the position of the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest (based on my own implementation of a similar use case):

- Have the position callback implementation accept references (in constructor) on:

  - PopupPanel element
  - element on which user right cliked
  - the content you put in the PopupPanel
- Replicate (I know this not DRY but implementation is package private) the code from default position callback
- When opening to the right invoke a method that changes the layout of your content (CSS based or otherwise)

I hope it helps. If you find something better let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't actually understand what you're suggesting here. Could you maybe add some sample code or such to clarify?